# Apex Oracle Student database tutorial question

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

What is wrong with this? Or could someone help me understand what this code is trying to do?

```sql
UPDATE copy_departments d
SET d.employee_name = (SELECT d.employee_name
FROM departments d
WHERE d.employee_name = d.department_id);
```

Comment: Could you please add an error (if any) you get and also your table/DB structure that may help to understand your issue and help you.

Comment: Error at line 2/5: ORA-00904: "D"."EMPLOYEE_NAME": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 847
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 833
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1903


1. UPDATE copy_departments d
2. SET d.employee_name = (SELECT d.employee_name
3. FROM departments d
4. WHERE d.employee_name = d.department_id);

Comment: You've tagged "mysql" and "oracle-apex". It cannot be both. oracle APEX only runs on the oracle database which is not the same as mysql

Comment: Please share the ddl for both tables so we don't have to guess...

Answer (score 2):

Error you got:

> Error at line 2/5: ORA-00904: "D"."EMPLOYEE_NAME": invalid identifier

is related to this:

```
SQL> update copy_departments d
  2  set d.employee_name = (select d.employee_name
  3                         from departments d
  4                         where d.employee_name = d.department_id);
set d.employee_name = (select d.employee_name
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "D"."EMPLOYEE_NAME": invalid identifier
```

See what the asterisk (*) points to? `d.employee_name`. What does it mean? It means that target table (`copy_department`) does NOT contain column named `employee_name`.

---

Other than that: table **aliases** are here to **help** us read and understand queries. Your choice is really poor, as you chose to use the same alias - `d` - for both tables (`departments` and `copy_departments`) so it is really impossible for us to guess which column belongs to which table. Use **different aliases**.

---

You asked what is that `update` trying to do: it wants to update `employee_name` in `copy_departments` table to `employee_name` column's value from the `departments` table, where the join condition is rather suspicious - you're saying that one (once again - no idea which one's because of the same aliases) table's employee **name** is equal to another table's department **id**?! Name equal to ID? Really?

From my point of view (note that I don't know your tables' description), something like this might make more sense:

```
update copy_departments c 
set c.employee_name = (select d.employee_name
                       from departments d
                       where d.department_id = c.department_id);
```